# Error while updating property "position" in shadow node of type: RCTView. null. invalid value for position: left

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-gifted-chat, expo-av

```js
const Chat = ({ route, navigation, db, isConnected, storage }) => {
// Get the `name` prop from the `route` object
 const { name, backgroundColor, userID } = route.params;

    // Initialize the `messages` state with an empty array
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

    let soundObject = null;

    // Function to append new messages to the `messages` state
    const onSend = (newMessages) => {
        addDoc(collection(db, 'messages'), newMessages[0]);
    };

    // Function to customize the appearance of chat bubbles
    const renderBubble = (props) => {
        return (
            <Bubble
                {...props}
                wrapperStyle={{
                    right: {
                        backgroundColor: '#000',
                    },
                    left: {
                        backgroundColor: '#fff',
                    },
                }}
            />
        );
    };

    const renderAudioBubble = (props) => {
        return (
            <View {...props}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={{ backgroundColor: '#FF0', borderRadius: 10, margin: 5 }}
                    onPress={async () => {
                        if (soundObject) soundObject.unloadAsync();
                        const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync({
                            uri: props.currentMessage.audio,
                        });
                        soundObject = sound;
                        await sound.playAsync();
                    }}
                >
                    <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', color: 'black', padding: 5 }}>
                        Play Sound
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    };

    let unsubMessages;
    // Initialize the `messages` state with some default messages when the component mounts for the first time
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isConnected === true) {
            // unregister current onSnapshot() listener to avoid registering multiple listeners when
            // useEffect code is re-executed.
            if (unsubMessages) unsubMessages();
            unsubMessages = null;

            navigation.setOptions({ title: name });
            // Query the 'messages' collection in Firestore for the chat messages, ordered by creation date
            const q = query(collection(db, 'messages'), orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'));
            // Subscribe to changes to the 'messages' collection in Firestore
            unsubMessages = onSnapshot(q, (docs) => {
                let newMessages = [];
                // Convert the Firestore document snapshots to an array of message objects
                docs.forEach((doc) => {
                    newMessages.push({
                        id: doc.id,
                        ...doc.data(),
                        createdAt: new Date(doc.data().createdAt.toMillis()),
                    });
                });
                // Update the `messages` state with the new messages
                cachedMessages(newMessages);
                setMessages(newMessages);
            });
        } else {
            // Load cached messages if offline
            loadCachedMessages();
        }

        // Unsubscribe from the 'messages' collection when the component unmounts
        return () => {
            if (unsubMessages) unsubMessages();
            if (soundObject) soundObject.unloadAsync();
        };
    }, [isConnected]);

    // Function to cache the messages in AsyncStorage
    const cachedMessages = async (messagesToCache) => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('messages', JSON.stringify(messagesToCache));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    };

    // Function to load cached messages from AsyncStorage
    const loadCachedMessages = async () => {
        const cachedMessages = (await AsyncStorage.getItem('messages')) || [];
        setMessages(JSON.parse(cachedMessages));
    };

    // Function to render the input toolbar based on network connectivity
    const renderInputToolbar = (props) => {
        if (isConnected) return <InputToolbar {...props} />;
        else return null;
    };

    const renderCustomView = (props) => {
        const { currentMessage } = props;
        if (currentMessage.location) {
            return (
                <MapView
                    style={{ width: 150, height: 100, borderRadius: 13, margin: 3 }}
                    region={{
                        latitude: currentMessage.location.latitude,
                        longitude: currentMessage.location.longitude,
                        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                    }}
                />
            );
        }
        return null;
    };

    const renderCustomActions = (props) => {
        return <CustomActions userID={userID} storage={storage} {...props} />;
    };

    return (
        <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor }]}>
            <GiftedChat
                messages={messages}
                renderBubble={renderBubble}
                renderInputToolbar={renderInputToolbar}
                onSend={onSend}
                renderActions={renderCustomActions}
                renderCustomView={renderCustomView}
                renderMessageAudio={renderAudioBubble}
                user={{
                    _id: route.params.userID,
                    name: route.params.name,
                }}
            />
            {/* Render the `KeyboardAvoidingView` component on Android devices to adjust the layout when the keyboard is shown */}
            {Platform.OS === 'android' ? (
                <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='height' />
            ) : null}
        </View>
    );
};
```

Comment: This is a Chat App. I have this error when I'm trying to test the app with Expo app. Everything was fine until I tried to implement the Audio feature.